# Android SQlite Database cursor column -1 error when fetching

Tags: database, android-studio, android-sqlite

error "E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 9 columns."

I am storing data in the database and sending to the server after that the code follows

this is database Tables

```
public static final String Table_NAME_5 ="_5";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID_5 = "SNo";
    public static final String COLUMN_Image_5 = "image";
    public static final String COLUMN_SiteID_5 = "siteid";
    public static final String COLUMN_FUserId_5 = "fuserid";
    public static final String COLUMN_CategoryId_5 ="categoryid";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID_SubCategoryId_5 = "subcategoryid";
    public static final String COLUMN_ChkPointsId_5 = "chkpointid";
    public static final String COLUMN_Rating_5 = "rating";
    public static final String COLUMN_Remark_5 = "remark";

    public static final String Table_NAME_6 ="_6";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID_6 =" SNo";
    public static final String COLUMN_Image_6 =" image";
    public static final String COLUMN_SiteID_6 ="siteid";
    public static final String COLUMN_FUserId_6 ="fuserid";
    public static final String COLUMN_CategoryId_6 ="categoryid";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID_SubCategoryId_6 ="subcategoryid";
    public static final String COLUMN_ChkPointsId_6 =" chkpointid";
    public static final String COLUMN_Rating_6 ="rating";
    public static final String COLUMN_Remark_6 ="remark";
```

```
String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE5 = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_NAME_5 + "(" + COLUMN_ID_5 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_Image_5 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_SiteID_5 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_FUserId_5 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_CategoryId_5 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_ID_SubCategoryId_5 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_ChkPointsId_5 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_Rating_5 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_Remark_5 +   " TEXT)";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEM_TABLE5);


String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE6 = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_NAME_6 + "(" + COLUMN_ID_6 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_Image_6 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_SiteID_6 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_FUserId_6 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_CategoryId_6 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_ID_SubCategoryId_6 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_ChkPointsId_6 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_Rating_6 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_Remark_6 +   " TEXT)";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEM_TABLE6);
```

Here I am inserting in both tables

```
myDB.Insertdata5(imageCode5,site_id,user_id,category_id,sub_category_id,check_poind_id,rating_five,Remark5);

myDB.Insertdata6(imageCode1,site_id,user_id,category_id,sub_category_id,check_poind_id,rating_one,Remark1);
```

Here I am Fetching it from the database (ERROR IS HERE)

```
 public String Table5 () {
        String R = "NOT EMPTY";
        DatabaseHandler myDB = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabaseObj = myDB.getWritableDatabase();
        long count1 = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(sqLiteDatabaseObj, DatabaseHandler.Table_NAME_5);
        if (count1 > 0) {
            for (long i = 1; i <= count1; i++) {
                count1 = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(sqLiteDatabaseObj, DatabaseHandler.Table_NAME_5);
                Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabaseObj.query(myDB.Table_NAME_5, null, myDB.COLUMN_ID_5 + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(i)}, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Senddata5(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_Image_5)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_SiteID_5)),
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_FUserId_5)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_CategoryId_5)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_ID_SubCategoryId_5)), "5", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_Rating_5)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_Remark_5)));
                        if (i == count1&& i== res_sucess5) {

                            myDB.RefreshTable5();

                            R = "EMPTY";
                        } else {
                            R = "NOT EMPTY";

                        }
                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        else{ R = "EMPTY";}          myDB.close();    return R;
    }
```

```
    public String Table6 () {
        String R = "NOT EMPTY";
        DatabaseHandler myDB = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabaseObj = myDB.getWritableDatabase();
        long count1 = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(sqLiteDatabaseObj, DatabaseHandler.Table_NAME_6);
        if (count1 > 0) {
            for (long i = 1; i <= count1; i++) {
                count1 = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(sqLiteDatabaseObj, DatabaseHandler.Table_NAME_6);
                Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabaseObj.query(myDB.Table_NAME_6, null, myDB.COLUMN_ID_6 + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(i)}, null, null, null);
                boolean cur = cursor.moveToFirst();
                Log.e("Optiontwo", String.valueOf(cur));

                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        
                       Senddata6(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_Image_6)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_SiteID_6)),
                               cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_FUserId_6)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_CategoryId_6)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_ID_SubCategoryId_6)), "6", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_Rating_6)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_Remark_6)));
                       if (i == count1&& i== res_sucess6) {

                            myDB.RefreshTable6();

                            R = "EMPTY";
                        } else {
                            R = "NOT EMPTY";

                        }

                       

                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }


                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        else{ R = "EMPTY";}          myDB.close();    return R;
    }
'''
```

Table 5 is working all fine and good but table 6 having an error when fetching COLUMN_Image_6.
Error is when I am fetching cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_Image_6)) only if i delete this "cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDB.COLUMN_Image_6))" then all values of other columns are fetched fine. Column_image is Base64 string i also tried BLOB byte[] but same problem. why it is working for table 5 but not for table 6.

the error I am getting is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it."

Comment: `public static final String COLUMN_Image_6 =" image"` – Remove the space before `image`. And do so for the other `COLUMN*`s that have spaces, too.

Comment: That's it thanks Mike M. it does the trick silly mistake it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as MIKE M pointed out the problem is space before column name. The problem is solved.